# HERE REST API (fleet.ls) Timezone return incorrect for Adelaide (Australia) possible half hour confuses API

Tags: here-api, timezone-offset, iso8601

HERE REST API fleet.ls

Consider the following REST API call.  Note the Long Lats are in Adelaide Australia which has a TZ of +9:30.

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=-34.8751,138.5276&waypoint1=-34.9042,138.5708;sort&waypoint2=stopOver,600!-34.893,138.5546;sort&departure=2021-01-08T17:15:00&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled&legAttributes=-li,-mn,le,bt,tt,-tm,sh&routeAttributes=sm,wp&apikey=xxxxxx

The Departure time is set to:
departure=2021-01-08T**17:15:00**

However the summary returns the following:

```
"summary": {
"travelTime": 1010,
"distance": 5102,
"baseTime": 882,
"trafficTime": 1010,
"flags": [],
"departure": "2021-01-08T**17:15:00+10**",
"arrival": "2021-01-08T17:31:49+10"
}
```

The absolute time is incorrect as the location has a timezone of +9.5 (or +10.5 DST).  This, is then passed through to other algorithms used and, well, messes everything up by a half an hour.

Comment: This looks like a bug.  They are truncating the offset to whole hours to present it with a two-digit hours-only offset.  The timestamps you gave should have hours and minutes components, as in `"2021-01-08T17:15:00+10:30"`.  I've edited your question tags appropriately, but if you are a paying customer of theirs, you should follow their support process as shown at: https://developer.here.com/help

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Not a paying customer yet, simply exploring how we might be able to use their services for our simulation software.  I hope they take a look at this and it has a simple resolution for them :-).

Comment: Actually it appears they've already fixed this in v8 of the API.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using version 7 of the Calculate Route API, [as shown here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html).  It shows timestamps with only whole-hour offsets, such as `2013-07-04T17:00:00+02`.

The [docs here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/8.0.0/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/calculate-route.html) for version 8+ of the API show a very different format for its output, including timestamps with full hours and minutes in the offset, such as `2019-12-09T16:05:05+01:00`.  The full example in docs is:

```json
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "id": "bfaed7d0-19c7-4e72-81b7-24eeb148b62b",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "arrival": {
                        "place": {
                            "location": {
                                "lat": 52.53232637420297,
                                "lng": 13.378873988986015
                            },
                            "type": "place"
                        },
                        "time": "2019-12-09T16:05:05+01:00"
                    },
                    "departure": {
                        "place": {
                            "location": {
                                "lat": 52.53098367713392,
                                "lng": 13.384566977620125
                            },
                            "type": "place"
                        },
                        "time": "2019-12-09T16:03:02+01:00"
                    },
                    "id": "85357f8f-00ad-447e-a510-d8c02e0b264f",
                    "summary": {
                        "duration": 123,
                        "length": 538
                    },
                    "transport": {
                        "mode": "car"
                    },
                    "type": "vehicle"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I suggest you use the latest v8 of the API  (8.14.0 at time of writing this).  It should give the correct offsets for Adelaide.